# Перекрестный запрос с вычислениями

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть две таблицы. Первая components:

- id
- name

Вторая assets:

- component_id
- price
- left

Не получается составить запрос, который вывел бы только уникальные Name и ID для одной таблицы, а для остальных двух столбцов второй таблицы вывел сумму.

Т.е. Если есть несколько строк с Name = "PC", то на выходе должна быть одна строчка, где Name = "PC", а Price = sum(price where name = "PC")

Answer (score 2):

Зачем вам подзапрос?

```
select "Name", sum("Price")
from tablename
group by "Name"
```

Comment: Выдает одинаковую сумму для всех Name. Сейчас выложу в вопрос то, что получилось

Comment: ну абсолютно неудивительно для декартова произведения. Тот запрос что вы добавили в вопрос не имеет к остальной формулировке вопроса никакого отношения абсолютно.

Comment: Помогите мне. Из того что я писал (и пишу) не работает ничего, но чую что должен быть вложенный запрос

Comment: Чем помогать если вы спрашиваете не то что потом проверяете и утаиваете критичные части вопроса? А именно что у вас `Name` и `price` - в разных таблицах вместо заявленной прямым текстом в вопросе одной таблицы? Для декартова объединения результат полностью очевидный, вам же вероятно нужен `inner join`.

Comment: Спасибо. Мне помог ваш совет, сделал, работает. Исправлю вопрос, оставлю ответ. Простите за утаивание, перестарался с упрощением для наглядности

Answer (score 0):

Нужен был INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT components.id, components.name, sum(assets.price) as "price", sum(assets.left) as "left"
FROM components
INNER JOIN assets ON assets.component_id = components.id
GROUP BY components.id
```